# ToastNotification during Quiet Time

Tags: windows-8

I have developed a desktop application which displays ToastNotifications while the user is in Metro Mode. When clicked it will bring the user back to the desktop mode where a standard desktop notification is presented.

This all works fine except when Windows is in QUNS_QUIET_TIME. The desktop notifications do not get displayed as expected, but the ToastNotfications still get displayed. My client wishes for the ToastNotifications to not display during Quiet Time.

The code calls SHQueryUserNotificationState which returns a [QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The provided link says the following:

> Note that during quiet time, if the user is in one of the other blocked modes (QUNS_NOT_PRESENT, QUNS_BUSY, QUNS_PRESENTATION_MODE, or QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN) SHQueryUserNotificationState returns only that value, and does not report QUNS_QUIET_TIME.

This is what I am experiencing. The call to SHQueryUserNotificationState is returning QUNS_APP (A Windows Store app is running.) and not QUNS_QUIET_TIME.

Does anyone know of another way to determine if QUNS_QUIET_TIME is in effect or a way to force the toast to respect quiet time?

Answer (score 0):

Desktop notifications use different [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) than toast notifications. You can find toast notification settings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.setting.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1). When a user sets notifications to one hour from Windows 8 Settings | Notifications, the app will not be able set toast notification. Try the example "[sending toast notifications from a desktop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2)" here (either C++ code or C# code).